How do I successfully use an interface from a TypeScript file that has its own import inside it?
I'm working on a React JavaScript project with WebStorm and trying to implement type hinting for our IDEs (VS Code as well) using TypeScript interfaces and JSDoc annotations (which hopefully we'll convert to full TypeScript in the future...)
It works if I reference the namespace and interface when the interface is in a file with no imports:
//cart.js
/**
 * @returns {Prep.Cart}
 */
export const fetchCart = (cached = false, type = queryTypes.FULL) =>

//cart.ts
declare namespace Prep {
  export interface Cart {
    CustomerNumber: number
    // ...
  }
}

However, I get the error TS2503: Cannot find namespace Prep if I have an import in the TypeScript file that contains the interface:
//cart.js
/**
 * @returns {Prep.Cart}
 */
export const fetchCart = (cached = false, type = queryTypes.FULL) =>

//cart.ts
import {Model} from 'sequelize'

declare namespace Prep {
  export interface Cart extends Model {
    CustomerNumber: number
    // ...
  }
}

And if I add another file that defines the namespace by itself, then I get the error TS2694: Namespace Prep has no exported member Cart:
// prep.ts
declare namespace Prep {}

So it seems like if there's an import in one of these TypeScript files then whatever is exported or declared from it isn't picked up.
Is there a better or different way to do this that allows me to reliably reference the namespace and interface while having the interface extend another type that's imported from another file or package?
Also, I do have a jsconfig.json and tsconfig.json that should be picking these up automatically. Everything works as expected otherwise so it seems to just be using an import in the TypeScript file.

Don't write both cart.js and cart.ts files. Either go to just cart.ts right await, or write a cart.d.ts next to your cart.js.

What kind of module system do you currently use?

The project isn't setup to run/"compile" ts files yet otherwise I would be writing everything in TypeScript. I'm just using .ts (or .d.ts) files just for namespaces and interfaces, and JSDocs to give type hinting/reminders to the IDE (which also gives me TypeScript errors even if the compilation step doesn't). It's a pretty old project, it's using WebPack and babel. I use ES6/TypeScript style imports and exports in my code, but behind the scenes I think it boils down to commonjs on the server and bundled javascript function names on the client.

Then I guess you should use proper module references instead of namespaces in your type declarations as well

Maybe I misunderstand how that's done, but I can't import .ts (or .d.ts) files in my .js files because it's not really a TypeScript project.

When you import a .js file with an accompanying .d.ts file, TypeScript will read the types from that declaration file

You can use *.d.ts to avoid conflict in your code:

Modify your tsconfig.json like this:
"include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts"]

Create a separate file .d.ts to put all your declarations inside.


